# how to set constraint in finding optimal values

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

For the finding optimal functions,

My objective function is `min(x1+x2+x3+x4)`
and constraints are

1. all `xi` should be equal or larger than zero
2. `sum(ai(xi+1)^bi) => LL`.  (`ai`, `bi` and `LL` values are given)

I think I should use `constrOptim` function, but I do not know how I should treat second constraint..

Comment: `=>`  should be `>=` I suppose...

Comment: The feasibility of this optimization appears to depend on the ai and b1 which are not given. I think there is insufficient information presented to allow coding to proceed and so the question is too general at the moment. There are SE section for both Mathematics and Statistics where this would be a better fit.

Comment: @BondedDust you're right. I'd say the most important parameter is bi. If all bi = 1, this can solved as a normal linear problem. If  bi can be 1 or 2 this is a linear problem with quadratic constraints. For all the other possible values of bi, this is basically a non-linear optimization problem.